# How to add colour to Hugo Tags

Tags: html, css, hugo

So I'm trying to get my hugo tags colorized, in other words, tags must display in a distinct color
for that, I follow this guide https://rajasimon.io/blog/hugo-colour-tags/
but getting error **unexpected EOF** when building site, also in vscode it says css-propertyvalueexpected and css-ruleorselectorexpected

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlDl7.png)

```html
{{ range $tag := .Params.tags }}
{{ if eq $tag "hugo" }}
  <span class="tag" style="background-color: {{ $.Site.Params.hugo }};">{{ $tag }}</span>
{{ else if eq $tag "gatsby" }}
  <span class="tag" style="background-color: {{ $.Site.Params.gatsby }};">{{ $tag }}</span>
{{ else }}
  <span class="tag" style="background-color: #000000;">{{ $tag }}</span> 
{{ end }}
```

Comment: FYI, `Unexpected EOF` means unexpected end of file. The most common reason is when someone forgets and ending curly-brace;

Comment: Yeah on the Hugo forum someone already mentions it but unfortunately, I've no idea where should I put it even I tried putting three end blocks but that not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this, most present version of hugo. Your IF statement needs an {{ end }} AND your RANGE statement needs an {{ end }} (see below), with that you should be fine.

```
{{ range $tag := .Params.tags }}
{{ if eq $tag "hugo" }}
  <span class="tag" style="background-color: {{ $.Site.Params.hugo }};">{{ $tag }}</span>
{{ else if eq $tag "gatsby" }}
  <span class="tag" style="background-color: {{ $.Site.Params.gatsby }};">{{ $tag }}</span>
{{ else }}
  <span class="tag" style="background-color: #000000;">{{ $tag }}</span> 
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```